# Is it possible connect android only to bluetooth board hc-06?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

i'm developing an app in android using eclipse and this aplication needs to connect a bluetooth board hc-06 with arduino.
Is it possible connect android only to bluetooth board hc-06? for example, i search bluetooth devices with my app and if i connect with another bluetooth device (without hc-06) the app shows a message like "wrong device".

Answer (score 0):

Set the HC-06's name to something you want.  In your Android code check for the name of the Bluetooth connected device.  Or, you could check the Bluetooth id, etc.

Comment: thanks, but is it possible with mac know if is a bluetooth board?

Comment: yes, you can either catalog the macs of the hc-06s you're using or you could try to just check the first three bytes of the mac which is the vendor id and should, in theory, be the same between boards.